# Why does git asks for key passphrase when ssh does not?

Tags: git, ssh, windows-10

I've looked through several of Q&As about why git asks for an SSH key passphrase every time, but I haven't found one that describes my situation. What makes my situation different is that I have successfully created an ssh key, added it to the agent, and the agent is running. So when I run:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

I immediately get the success message "You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access." It does not ask for a passphrase.

The perplexing thing is that in powershell when I navigate to a git repo associated with that account, and run a git command like this:

```
cd ~/mygitrepo
git fetch
```

I get asked to `Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\me\.ssh\github'`.

If I enter the passphrase, I successfully can fetch from the repo.

Why am I asked to enter the passphrase when running a `git` command but not when running an `ssh` command?

### Extra details

I'm running Windows 10, using PowerShell inside Windows Terminal.
I use ssh everyday to connect to various remotes and it never asks for a passphrase.

Snippet from ~/.ssh/config

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile C:\Users\me\.ssh\github
```

Snippet from ~/mygitrepo/.git/config

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:myuser/myrepo.git
```

Comment: Git *comes with* its own ssh; Windows 10 also comes with *its* own ssh. Your two different ssh installations are failing to talk to each other. If your Windows ssh is capable of doing everything Git needs (it probably is, not sure about this as I don't use Windows but Windows 10 is probably new enough) you probably just want to convince Git to use the Windows ssh.

Comment: (In this particular case, I think the Git ssh is looking for a different agent, leading to the need for a passphrase.) Setting GIT_SSH_COMMAND in the environment, or `core.sshCommand` in your global Git config, should fix this.

Comment: Aweome, @torek I can't tell you how many hours I have spent on this problem and you found the reason for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run a git command, by default it uses its own version of ssh, which fails to communicate with the Windows ssh-agent.

Find out what binary Windows is using:

```
Powershell> where.exe ssh
CMD> where ssh
```

For me the result is `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH`. Now force git to use that binary by setting the following line in your global `.gitconfig` file:

```
[core]
    sshCommand = "C:/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe"
...
```